# Cross Browser Support for Coded UI

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I have Recorded Coded UI Test With Silverlight 5 Application With IE Browser. but when i am trying to Run it for Chrome it's not working.

For non silverlight application it is working fine.

I have installed Cross Browser plugin for chrome.

Comment: "Not working" is a very broad term, can you be more specific? Also have you checked the links from the "Platform Support" section of the "Content Index for Coded UI Test" at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2010/02/11/content-index-for-coded-ui-test.aspx to see whether your software combination is supported?

Comment: When i try to run the test with Chrome, Test Successfully Opens Chrome with Desired web address but then test fails. when i checked the log for the same it says it could not find the controls to action upon.

Comment: I think you'll find cross browser support is limited to doing pure web testing only (i.e. HTML/DOM related tests) and doesn't support Silverlght.

Comment: Ya, That's what i have experienced till date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, Cross browser testing is only for web applications. Silverlight testing is not supported in Chrome or Firefox.

Since Silverlight is a browser plug in, if something works in Silverlight/IE then you can rely on it working in FF and Chrome. If it fails then it's a problem with Silverlight, not your application.